# How do I convert values from environment variables from string to int to use as application properties in my Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, docker-compose, docker-swarm, spring-cloud-stream

I have a dockerized Spring Cloud Stream service, and I'm trying to read values for **instanceCount** and **instanceIndex** from environment variables set on the virtual machine on which the service is running. I have a class marked with the @ConfigurationProperties annotation:

```
package com.hines.james.converters;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.stream")
public class NodeSpringCloudStreamProperties {
    private int instanceCount;
    private int instanceIndex;

    public int getInstanceCount() {
        return instanceCount;
    }

    public void setInstanceCount(int instanceCount) {
        this.instanceCount = instanceCount;
    }

    public int getInstanceIndex() {
        return instanceIndex;
    }

    public void setInstanceIndex(int instanceIndex) {
        this.instanceIndex = instanceIndex;
    }
}
```

and a converter:

```
package com.hines.james.converters;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class StringToIntegerConverter implements Converter<String, Integer>{
    @Override
    public Integer convert(String source) {
        return Integer.valueOf(source);
    }
}
```

and my application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      instanceCount: ${NUM_NODES}
      instanceIndex: ${NODE_INDEX}
```

values for **NUM_NODES** and **NODE_INDEX** for this particular vm have been set in a previous step.

When I debug the service through my IDE, I can see that values are being set for instanceCount and instanceIndex. When I deploy the app, I get a ConverterNotFoundException, with this message (there's a similar message for NUM_NODES):

```
Field error in object 'spring.cloud.stream' on field 'instanceIndex': rejected value [${NODE_INDEX}]; codes [typeMismatch.spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex,typeMismatch.instanceIndex,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex,instanceIndex]; arguments []; default message [instanceIndex]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'instanceIndex'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [int]]
```

I'm using docker compose to define my multi container application, and docker swarm to deploy it.

How do I convert values from environment variables from string to int to use as application properties in my Spring Boot application?

Comment: From the looks of it, it looks like `${NUM_NODES}` isn't getting translated properly.  How are you filling those values in?

Comment: Have you tried removing the converter all together? Such converters aren't generally needed, Spring takes care of them

Comment: As @geoand pointed out you probably have a lot going on here that is not needed including NodeSpringCloudStreamProperties. A simple `@Value("${NUM_NODES}")` annotation on the `int` field would take care of it (including the conversion since its a simple String to Int and is supported out of the box)

Comment: @Makoto, the values are set in /etc/environment. Spring should be pulling them in like any other environment variable.

Comment: You may be conflating `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Value`.  I would expect the former to be coming from a properties file or the command line, and the latter to be coming from a properties file, the command line, or a global environment variable.  This doesn't change the fact that **you have to be sure that the environment variable gets properly translated to the value you need**, or it will always be a String.

Comment: The **NUM_NODES** and **NODE_INDEX** values aren't being used in any application logic. For some reason the conversion isn't working for values in application.yml. Is it possible to use @Value in a properties file?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what "not working" means. If you have 'NUM_NODES' defined as a property (in the file) or System property, or Environment variable then by simply annotation a field with `@Value` (as mentioned above) would work (and in fact the above also specifies the search order). This is at the very core of Spring for over a decade. And if it doesn't work for you let's prove or disprove you configuration since most definitely something is going on there.